# Is it possible to download a Linux bootable operating system direct to a wiped HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

*I am in the hospital and have no money so don't need advise me to get a USB drive please.*

---

I purchased a laptop which ended up having BitLocker enabled when I disabled secure boot.

I have a 3.5GB USB drive which I managed to get a Linux live ISO on and am now able to use the laptop, however it will not install with error code 5.

I have spent hours looking up possible solutions but nothing seems easy enough.

I just want to know if there is a way I can possibly download direct to the HDD and make it bootable? I don't want to format my USB drive and burn another ISO to it in case it fails and I can no longer use the system.

This is only an issue due to me being in hospital and no access to resources right now.

It sounds like it should be viable but I am really new to Linux and having a limited 3.5GB USB drive has stopped me being able to download Windows again. I want an operating system on bare metal so I have access to the laptop.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: No, not possible is the short answer. Now, "error code 5" seems not to be an error in any Linux installation that I'm aware of. We may try to help you with the installation but details are needed, namely the hardware specifications and the Linux distro you already have, at the very least. Also describe exactly how are you trying to install it and what errors show up.

Comment: Why did you disabled Secure Boot? Have you tried to re-nable it? It's probably all it needs to run the preinstalled Windows normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is impossible, but there are simpler solutions.

Your computer came with Windows, so it would be simpler
to use WSL and install a complete ready-made Linux
distribution from the Microsoft Store.

Another method would be to create a virtual machine and install
Linux from the ISO.

You will need to enable back the Secure Boot.

These solutions do not need additional hardware.

(*Wishing you a quick recovery*.)

Comment: Nice suggestions but the author *purchased a laptop which ended up having BitLocker enabled when I disabled secure boot* so neither is applicable because somehow the Windows is working.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I'm not sure : A new computer would normally come with Windows 11 and a Bitlocked disk. If he didn't wipe out Windows, Secure Boot is needed and Bitlocker is not a problem in Windows. He just needs to return to the original setup.

Comment: Agreed and commented just now asking for clarification.

Comment: @harrymc - If the author disabled Secure Boot, upon the required reboot, immediately the BitLocker recovery key would be required

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, that's likely one of his problems.

Comment: sorry i had no wsl i literally just got the boot up message no os installed but thank you for the help I am up and running now. greatly appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

It very much is possible. You have a Linux system already and that means you can install many other Linux systems directly from the internet. You just need to do everything an installer might normally do yourself. The keyword is “install Linux from Linux”.

The rough steps would be:

1. Partition the disk: Typically 512 MB for `/boot`, maybe 4 GB for swap and then the rest for `/`
2. Make filesystems: Check `mkfs.ext4`, default options are fine, and `mkswap`. Don’t forget to mount them at /mnt, /mnt/boot and to activate swap.
3. Decide which Distro to use. Debian is really easy to install with `debootstrap` and Arch is also good with `pacstrap`. Because Ubuntu is Debian-based, it can also be installed using `debootstrap`. Guides on the internet will be more up-to-date.
4. Perform the initial installation, possibly adapting the freshly installed system’s `/etc/fstab` afterwards.
5. `chroot` into the newly created system, maybe install additional packages as required to access the internet. You can come back to this step at any time if it doesn’t work out.
6. Set up a regular user account, maybe add it to the `wheel` group so it can use `sudo`. Mabye also give the `root` user a password, just in case.
7. Install and set up a boot loader. Could be as easy as `apt install grub-pc` or `apt install grub-efi-amd64` followed by `grub-install /dev/sda`.

Your Live USB will remain as-is and can be used again to fix stuff if the install somehow didn’t work out.

---

If your laptop has a Windows logo sticker, it likely has an embedded Windows license that you could use to reinstall Windows in the future. If not, be aware that this will wipe whatever Windows is on there irreversibly.

Comment: thank you i decided be brave and install parrot iso as it was 2.8gb and verified checksum I now have a working system and am happy. thank you so much for the responses greatly appreciated I hope to learn linux now and.